# Given order statistics find the probability the median lies between to $X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(7)}$

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Given a sample $X_{(1)},...,X_{(8)}$ from a continuous distribution find the $P(X_{(2)} < m < X_{(7)})$ where $m$ is the population median.

My initial questions are

Do I need to make the use of $P(X \le m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$ and $\, P(X \ge m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$ where $X$ is a random variable from this distribution.

Would this be something along the lines of $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^m\int_{m}^\infty f_{X_{(2)},X_{(7)}}(y,z)dydz$ ?

Where $f_{X_{(2)},X_{(7)}}(y,z) = \frac{8!}{4!}f(y)f(z)[F(y)][F(z)-F(y)]^4[1-F(z)]$

Comment: How do you define the median?  Is it not $m=(X_{(4)} + X_{(5)})/2$?  Which is by definition between $X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(7)}$.

Comment: @SherwinLott That is a good question because I have seen it for order statistics be defined as the order statistic such that $i=\lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor$ or $i=\lceil (n+1)/2 \rceil $

Comment: Perhaps you mean the sample is $X_1,\ldots,X_8$ and $m$ is population median.

Comment: @StubbornAtom This must be the case because otherwise there seems to be nothing to solve.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I have added that assumption to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_{(2)} < m < X_{(7)}$ is not the case, then either $m \leq X_{(2)}$ or $X_{(7)} \leq m$.

$$P(X_{(2)} < m < X_{(7)}) = 1 - P(m \leq X_{(2)}) - P(X_{(7)} \leq m)$$

The number of draws that are below $m$ follows a binomial distribution $n=8$ and $p=1/2$, thus:

$$\begin{align}
P(m \leq X_{(2)}) = P(X_{(7)} \leq m) &= 2^{-8}{8 \choose 0} + 2^{-8}{8 \choose 1} \\
&= 9\cdot 2^{-8} 
\end{align}$$

In conclusion:
$$\begin{align}
P(X_{(2)} < m < X_{(7)}) &= 1 - 9\cdot2^{-8} - 9\cdot2^{-8} \\
&= \frac{238}{256}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think I follow this for the most part, a couple questions: 
1) $P(m \leq X_{(2)}) = P(X_{(7)} \leq m)$ follows from $P(X \le m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$ and $\, P(X \ge m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$ ? ;
2) For  $P(X_{(2)} < m < X_{(7)}) = 1 - P(m \leq X_{(2)}) - P(X_{(7)} \leq m)$ theres no issue with independence here? Seeing as order statistics are not independent.

Comment: 2) We have an event $E = X_{(2)} < m < X_{(7)}$, and its complement $E^{c}$ is the union of $m \leq X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(7)} \leq m$ which are disjoint events. (Yes, the order statistics are not independent, but this still follows.)

Comment: Sorry, your answer to question 1 isn't quite clear all you added was $P(X_{(7)} \le m)$ Did you mean $P(X_{(7)} \ge m) = P(X_{(2)} \le m) = P(X_{(7)} \le m)  $. For 2) I see why they are disjoint now, thank you.

Comment: (Sorry, I've fixed the typos.)  1) I could have separately written:
$$\begin{align} P(X_{(7)} \leq m) &= 2^{-8}{8 \choose 7} + 2^{-8}{8 \choose 8} \\ &= 9\cdot 2^{-8}  \end{align}$$
But, I decided to condense it via symmetry for a binomial with $p=1/2$.  The point being that if we computed $P(X_{(7)} \leq m) $ separately from $P(m \leq X_{(2)})$ via the binomial argument, then we end up with the same expression for both of them. (Emphasis on the difference in the binomial coefficients.)